# How to shift arrow horizontally?

Tags: flow-charts

I have drawn a flowchart described on the left side using the following code... However, I want to draw as described on the left-hand side. I want to shift the arrows left/right instead of in the center on L - BFGS box.

[image]

Hi, I want to make a flowchart as described on the right-hand side of the above figure. e.g., one arrow is going down from L BFGS to AKR & Gradient and then another arrow is going up from AKR to L BFGS. Downgoing arrows are on the left side of the rectangle while upgoing arrows are on the right side of the box/rectangle.

On the code, I shared, how I can edit it?

The code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=0.9cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{second} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=1.5cm, 
minimum height=0.7cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{optimizer} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=4cm, 
minimum height=1.2cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{true} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=1.5cm, 
minimum height=0.7cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, 
trapezium stretches=true, % A later addition
trapezium left angle=90, 
trapezium right angle=90, 
minimum width=5cm, 
minimum height=1.5cm, text centered, 
draw=black, fill=white]

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm, 
text centered, 
text width=3cm, 
draw=black, 
fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm, 
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thin,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.0cm]
        \node (start) [startstop] {Initial $S_{wo}$,\:$P_{eo}$};
        \node (sec) [second, below of=start] {$m_{S_w}$,\:$m_{P_e}$};
        \node (bfg) [optimizer, right of=sec, xshift=2.0cm] {\textbf{L - BFGS}};
        \node (tr) [second, below of=bfg, node distance=3cm] {$S_w$,\:$P_e$};
        \node (aki) [io, below of=tr, node distance=3cm] {\textbf{AKR \& Gradient}};
        
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- node[anchor=west] {$L$} (sec);
        \draw [arrow] (sec) -- (bfg);
        \draw [arrow] (bfg) -- node[anchor=west] {$L^{-1}$} (tr);
        \draw [arrow] (tr) -- (aki);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I want to make a flowchart as described on the right-hand side of the above figure. e.g., one arrow is going down from L BFGS to AKR & Gradient and then another arrow is going up from AKR to L BFGS. Downgoing arrows are on the left side of the rectangle while upgoing arrows are on the right side of the box/rectangle. 

On the code I shared, how I can edit it

Comment: Just wondering: Is the positioning library included in shapes.geometric or arrows? If not, it seems to be missing.

Comment: @NisarAhmed Unrelated to your question, but please note that `\tikzstyle` is deprecated. Have a look at `\tikzset` instead

Comment: Welcome to TeX. You included your text inside your image caption which meant none of us could see it until I edited your question. Please make sure your descriptions are in the text of your question and not image captions please :)

Answer (score 4):

Is this you want?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=0.9cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{second} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=1.5cm, 
minimum height=0.7cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{optimizer} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=4cm, 
minimum height=1.2cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{true} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=1.5cm, 
minimum height=0.7cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, 
trapezium stretches=true, % A later addition
trapezium left angle=90, 
trapezium right angle=90, 
minimum width=5cm, 
minimum height=1.5cm, text centered, 
draw=black, fill=white]

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm, 
text centered, 
text width=3cm, 
draw=black, 
fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm, 
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thin,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.0cm]
        \node (start) [startstop] {Initial $S_{wo}$,\:$P_{eo}$};
        \node (sec) [second, below of=start] {$m_{S_w}$,\:$m_{P_e}$};
        \node (bfg) [optimizer, right of=sec, xshift=2.0cm] {\textbf{L - BFGS}};
        \node (tr) [second, below of=bfg, node distance=3cm,xshift=-1cm,yshift=0cm] {$S_w$,\:$P_e$};
        \node (trb) [second,draw=blue, right of=tr, node distance=2cm,yshift=-1cm] {\color{blue}$J_r$};
        \node (trc) [second,draw=blue, right of=tr, node distance=2cm,yshift=1cm] {\color{blue}$J$};
        \node (aki) [io, below of=bfg, node distance=6cm] {\textbf{AKR \& Gradient}};
        
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- node[anchor=west] {$L$} (sec);
        \draw [arrow] (sec) -- (bfg);
        \draw [arrow] ([xshift=-1cm]bfg.south) -- node[anchor=west] {$L^{-1}$} (tr);
        \draw [arrow] (tr) -- ([xshift=-1cm]aki.north);
        \draw [arrow,blue] (trc) -- node[anchor=west] {$J+J_r$} ([xshift=1cm]bfg.south);
        \draw [arrow,blue] (trb) -- node[anchor=west] {$J$} (trc.south);
        \draw [arrow,blue] ([xshift=1cm]aki.north) -- node[anchor=west] {$J_r$} (trb);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Thanks, Yes, but can you please help here to shift AKR & Gradient box to move a bit towards the right side direction? I mean AKR & Gradient should be below (centralized) the L - BFGS rectangle.

Comment: I have updated the code to achieve what you asked for. Please check it out if this is the desired output.

Comment: dear many thanks, but one last help if modify that code for the following figure... I just want two boxes when it goes back from ARK & gradient to L BFGS, just shown by blue

Comment: @NisarAhmed It seems strange to add the figure of what you want to the answer. Why don't you add it to your question?

Comment: @NisarAhmed Any way I have upadated once more the code to give you a point to build on. I hope this will help you more.

Comment: Thank dear, it is working

Answer (score 4):

Some cosmetics to @miltos answer:

[image]

**Code**:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzstyle{startstop} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=0.9cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{second} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=1.5cm, 
minimum height=0.7cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{optimizer} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=4cm, 
minimum height=1.2cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{true} = [rectangle, rounded corners, 
minimum width=1.5cm, 
minimum height=0.7cm,
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=white]

\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, 
trapezium stretches=true, % A later addition
trapezium left angle=90, 
trapezium right angle=90, 
minimum width=5cm, 
minimum height=1.5cm, text centered, 
draw=black, fill=white]

\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm, 
text centered, 
text width=3cm, 
draw=black, 
fill=orange!30]

\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, 
minimum width=3cm, 
minimum height=1cm, 
text centered, 
draw=black, 
fill=green!30]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thin,->,>=stealth]

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.0cm]
        \node (start) [startstop] {Initial $S_{wo}$,\:$P_{eo}$};
        \node (sec) [second, below of=start] {$m_{S_w}$,\:$m_{P_e}$};
        \node (bfg) [optimizer, right of=sec, xshift=2.0cm] {\textbf{L - BFGS}};
        \node (tr) [second, below of=bfg, node distance=3cm,xshift=-1cm] {$S_w$,\:$P_e$};
        \node[line width=2pt] (trb) [second, right of=tr, node distance=2cm] {\bfseries $JR$};
        \node (aki) [io, below of=tr, node distance=3cm] {\textbf{AKR \& Gradient}};
        
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- node[anchor=west] {$L$} (sec);
        \draw [arrow] (sec) -- (bfg);
        \draw [arrow] ([xshift=-1cm]bfg.south) -- node[anchor=west] {$L^{-1}$} (tr);
        \draw [arrow] (tr) -- (aki);
        \draw [arrow,line width=2pt,double] (trb) -- node[anchor=west] {$J+J_r$} ([xshift=1cm]bfg.south);
        \draw [arrow,line width=2pt,double] ([xshift=2cm]aki.north) -- node[anchor=west] {$J$} (trb);
        
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```